# How can I separate numbers and letters in a C++ String?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, c++11, gcc

I'm having several input strings containing numbers and letters. Sometimes the space is missing. I would like to add an additional Space each time the string changes from numbers to letters or from letters to numbers.

Example inputs:

```
"30EinsteinStreet"
"548 Roe Drive5500 TestCity"
"44B SaarlouisDrive1234Testtown"
```

they should become:

```
"30 EinsteinStreet"
"548 Roe Drive 5500 TestCity"
"44 B SaarlouisDrive 1234 Testtown"
```

My existing function is not working and I think far to complex. Can anyone provide an easy solution? Preferably using modern C++11 classes but no Boost. Also I'm using GCC so all the regex stuff doesn't work for me.

Thanks

Here is my existing method:

```
        inline string separateAlphanumChunks(const std::string& s) 
        {
            string ret = "";
            const int sl = s.length();
            //int inserts = 0;

            if (sl<=4)
                return s;

            for (int i=0 ; i< sl ; i++)
            {
//              cerr << "separateAlphanumChunks: '" << ret << "'" <<endl;
                // check if index would go out of range
                if (i+4 > sl)
                {
                    ret += s.substr (i,sl-i);
                    //TODO add the remain to ret
                    break;
                }

                // seperate chars
                const char c0 = s[i+0];
                const char c1 = s[i+1];

                // check if 0 and 1 are the same class
                const bool c0c = isCharAnInt (c0);
                const bool c1c = isCharAnInt (c1);
                bool class0 = false;
                if (c0c == c1c)
                {
                    class0 = c0c;
                }
                else
                {
                    ret += c0;
//                  cerr << "cont1: '" << c0 << "'" <<endl;
                    continue;
                }

                // seperate chars
                const char c2 = s[i+2];
                const char c3 = s[i+3];

                // check if 2 and 3 are the same class
                const bool c2c = isCharAnInt (c2);
                const bool c3c = isCharAnInt (c3);
                bool class2 = false;
                if (c2c == c3c)
                {
                    class2 = c2c;
                }
                else
                {
                    ret += c0;
//                  cerr << "cont2: '" << c0 << "'" <<endl;
                    continue;
                }

                // check if the 2 classes are different
                if (class0 != class2)
                {
                    // split!
                    ret += c0+(c1+string(" ")+c2)+c3;
                    //inserts++;
                    i+=3;
                }
                else
                {
                    ret += c0;
//                  cerr << "cont3: '" << c0 << "'" <<endl;
                    continue;
                }

            }

            // remove double spaces
            //replaceStringInPlace(ret, "  "," "); 
            //cerr << "separateAlphanumChunks: '" << ret << "'" <<endl;
            return ret;
        }

    inline bool isCharAnInt (char c)
    {
        //TODO might be able to use isdigit() here
        int i = c - '0';
        return ((i>=0) && (i<=9));
    }
```

Comment: `std::regex` and/or `std::regex_iterator`

Comment: @stijn I forgot to say, that I didn't look into any of the regex functions because I'm using GCC. <regex> is only partly implemented and buggy in GCC. https://www.google.com.au/search?q=std::regex+gcc ... I'll fix the question.

Comment: @KenyakornKetsombut: Well, how about [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/regex) then?

Comment: @KenyakornKetsombut: No it's not. GCC 4.9 was released months ago.

Answer (score 2):

I saw various complex answers, and this is the reason to give another answer too.
The answer of your problem is exactly in the problem statement:
"add an additional Space each time the string changes from numbers to letters or from letters to numbers."

So here is exactly what you want ( I used some code from a previous answer ) the compilation should be done using the flag -std=c++11

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

enum charTypeT{ other, alpha, digit};

charTypeT charType(char c){
    if(isdigit(c))return digit;
    if(isalpha(c))return alpha;
    return other;
}

string separateThem(string inString){
  string oString = "";charTypeT st=other;
    for(auto c:inString){
        if( (st==alpha && charType(c)==digit) || (st==digit && charType(c)==alpha) )
          oString.push_back(' ');
        oString.push_back(c);st=charType(c);
    }
    return oString;
}

int main(){
  string str1 = "30EinsteinStreet";
  string str2 = "548 Roe Drive5500 TestCity";
  string str3 = "44B SaarlouisDrive1234Testtown";

  cout << separateThem(str1) << endl;
  cout << separateThem(str2) << endl;
  cout << separateThem(str3) << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for and what Ajay is hinting at is a [finite-state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) to parse strings.
Although this is not a C++11 solution, and you might find more elegant solutions by means of regex, I provided the code sample below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

bool isDigit(const char c)
{
    bool res = true;
    switch (c)
    {
        case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':
        case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9':
            break;

        default:
            res = false;
            break;
    }
    return res;
}

std::string separateNumbers(const std::string& inputString)
{
    const size_t N = inputString.length();
    std::ostringstream os;
    bool readDigit = false;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        if (isDigit(inputString[i]))
        {
            if ((i > 0) && (i < N) && (! readDigit))
            {
                if (inputString[i] != ' ')
                    os << ' ';
            }
            readDigit = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if ((i > 0) && (i < N) && (readDigit))
            {
                if (inputString[i] != ' ')
                    os << ' ';
            }
            readDigit = false;
        }
        os << inputString[i];
    }
    return os.str();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::string strings[3] = {
        "30EinsteinStreet",
        "548 Roe Drive5500 TestCity",
        "44B SaarlouisDrive1234Testtown"
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "input #" << i << ": " << strings[i] << std::endl;
        std::cout << "output #" << i << ": " << separateNumbers(strings[i]) << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: BTW: you can re-use your function isCharAnInt(), of course.

Comment: Your isDigit implementation is gross. `c>='0' && c<='9'` is enough

Comment: @Ajay: Only if you're stamping all over robustness and portability and blithely assuming ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my five cents.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

std::string SeparateAlphanumChunks( const std::string &s )
{
    std::string::size_type n = 0;
    bool ctype = std::isdigit( s[0] );

    for ( char c : s )
    {
        if ( !ctype != !std::isdigit( c ) )
        {
            ctype = std::isdigit( c );
            if ( !isblank( c ) ) ++n;
        }
    }

    std::string t;
    t.reserve( s.size() + n );

    ctype = std::isdigit( s[0] );

    for ( char c : s )
    {
        if ( !ctype != !std::isdigit( c ) )
        {
            ctype = std::isdigit( c );
            if ( !isblank( c ) ) t.push_back( ' ');
        }
        t.push_back( c );
    }

    return t;
}

int main() 
{
    for ( const std::string &s : { "30EinsteinStreet",
                                   "548 Roe Drive5500 TestCity",
                                   "44B SaarlouisDrive1234Testtown" 
                                 } )
    {
        std::cout << SeparateAlphanumChunks( s ) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
30 EinsteinStreet
548 Roe Drive 5500 TestCity
44 B SaarlouisDrive 1234 Testtown
```

You also may change the string "in place". For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

std::string & SeparateAlphanumChunks( std::string &s )
{
    std::string::size_type n = 0;
    bool ctype = std::isdigit( s[0] );

    for ( char c : s )
    {
        if ( !ctype != !std::isdigit( c ) )
        {
            ctype = std::isdigit( c );
            if ( !isblank( c ) ) ++n;
        }
    }

    s.reserve( s.size() + n );

    ctype = std::isdigit( s[0] );

    for ( std::string::size_type i = 0; i < s.size(); i++ )
    {
        if ( !ctype != !std::isdigit( s[i] ) )
        {
            ctype = std::isdigit( s[i] );
            if ( !isblank( s[i] ) ) 
            {
                s.insert( i, 1, ' ' );
            }
        }
    }

    return s;
}


int main() 
{
    for ( std::string s : { "30EinsteinStreet",
                            "548 Roe Drive5500 TestCity",
                                "44B SaarlouisDrive1234Testtown" 
                              } )
    {
        std::cout << SeparateAlphanumChunks( s ) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I would suggest is to go trough a iteration trough string elements.
Something like that will help:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string separateThem(string inString){
  string numbers = "1234567890";
  string oString = "";
  int i;
  for(i=0; i<inString.size()-1; i++){
    if ((numbers.find(inString[i]) != string::npos) && (numbers.find(inString[i+1]) == string::npos) && !isspace(inString[i+1])){
      oString += inString.substr(i,1) + " ";
    }
    else if ((numbers.find(inString[i]) == string::npos) && (numbers.find(inString[i+1]) != string::npos) && !isspace(inString[i+1])){
      oString += inString.substr(i,1) + " ";
    }
else oString += inString.substr(i,1);
  }
  oString += inString.substr(i,1);
  return oString;
}

int main(){
  string str1 = "30EinsteinStreet";
  string str2 = "548 Roe Drive5500 TestCity";
  string str3 = "44B SaarlouisDrive1234Testtown";

  cout << separateThem(str1) << endl;
  cout << separateThem(str2) << endl;
  cout << separateThem(str3) << endl;
}
```

If you execute this the output will be:

```
30 EinsteinStreet
548 Roe Drive 5500 TestCity
44 B SaarlouisDrive 1234 Testtown
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to GCC 4.9 (whose first release was back in April) and use a simple regex:

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

std::string fix(const std::string& in)
{
    return std::regex_replace(
        in,
        std::regex("(?:([a-zA-Z])([0-9]))|(?:([0-9])([a-zA-Z]))"),
        "\\1\\3 \\2\\4",
        std::regex_constants::format_sed
    );
}

int main()
{
    const std::string in[] = {
        "30EinsteinStreet",
        "548 Roe Drive5500 TestCity",
        "44B SaarlouisDrive1234Testtown"
    };

    for (auto el : in)
        std::cout << fix(el) << '\n';
}

/*
"30 EinsteinStreet"
"548 Roe Drive 5500 TestCity"
"44 B SaarlouisDrive 1234 Testtown"
*/
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/db6922de4a509238))

Comment: I'm not quite sure why `std::regex("(?:([:alpha:])([:digit:]))|(?:([:digit:])([:alpha:]))")` doesn't work, mind you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to iterator the `string` as raw-string (i.e. `string::c_str()`), and generate a new string altogether. This would be my algorithm (not very complete):

- For each character, check if it is a digit. If no, just append to new string.
- If yes, check if it is first character - if yes, just append to new string.
- If the digit is last character, then append to new string.
- If digit is falling in between, check if last appended character was space. If no space was there, put a space, and then put digit.
- If last inserted character was a digit, and this is also a digit, insert.
- However, if last was digit, but this is not a digit (and not a space), then insert a space.

You may need to tweak it further.

What if string is like this:

```
"enter 144    code   here    123    "
```

?

Comment: To your question: I think I can remove duplicated spaces later by another function. Should be easy. Maybe that's not even necessary. The basic problem is only that the input doesn't have enough spaces. To many spaces is currently not an issue.